# Mysql Query to find the status of the SKU items manufactured

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a delay table (as below) where a SKU is identified by the combination of mmodel and srno and the snapdate.. A SKU present on a specific snapdate indicates the SKU was delayed on that date

**Delay Table**

```
mmodel  Srno    Snapdate
MX201   C12341  3/21/2021
NM213   L1234   3/21/2021
JK1231  K1561   3/21/2021
KL1234  MJ1234  3/21/2021
MX201   C12341  3/22/2021
NM213   L1234   3/22/2021
OP1231  JK123   3/22/2021
MB321   LK123   3/22/2021
MX201   C12341  3/23/2021
BX378   H1231   3/23/2021
LZ231   MD321   3/23/2021
LO3412  LP1231  3/23/2021
MX201   C12341  3/24/2021
BX378   H1231   3/24/2021
FE221   J6571   3/24/2021
```

**Mfg table**

```
mfgdate mmodel  Srno
3/21/2021   JK123   K21310
3/21/2021   KL378   L8941
3/22/2021   JK1231  K1561
3/22/2021   KL1234  MJ1234
3/22/2021   KL918   S21367
3/23/2021   NM213   L1234
3/23/2021   OP1231  JK123
3/23/2021   MB321   LK123
3/23/2021   XC2312  M89321
3/24/2021   LZ231   MD321
3/24/2021   LO3412  LP1231
3/24/2021   KL5612  D3489
```

The above table has the mfgdate (date when the SKU got manufactured). Now I want to create a status table (as below) and ignore the first date in the above two tables and start from the second date.

**Status output table**

```
Date    mmodel  Srno    SKUComplete     Goodstock   offdelay    NewDelay
3/22/2021   JK1231  K1561   1   0   1   0
3/22/2021   KL1234  MJ1234  1   0   1   0
3/22/2021   KL918   S21367  1   1   0   0
3/22/2021   OP1231  JK123   0   0   0   1
3/22/2021   MB321   LK123   0   0   0   1
3/23/2021   NM213   L1234   1   0   1   0
3/23/2021   OP1231  JK123   1   0   1   0
3/23/2021   MB321   LK123   1   0   1   0
3/23/2021   XC2312  M89321  1   1   0   0
3/23/2021   BX378   H1231   0   0   0   1
3/23/2021   LZ231   MD321   0   0   0   1
3/23/2021   LO3412  LP1231  0   0   0   1
3/24/2021   LO3412  LP1231  1   0   1   0
3/24/2021   KL5612  D3489   1   1   0   0
3/24/2021   FE221   J6571   0   0   0   1
```

The above table is got by looking up the mfg table first, and the SKU present in the mfg table would be marked as SKUComplete 1 ..Now the same SKU should be looked up in the delay table on the previous date (Mfgdate-1)..If the SKU is present in the previous date in the delay table then offdelay would become 1 otherwise goodstock would become 1

After completing all the SKU'S in the mfg table for a particular manufacturing date the remaining SKU'S should be looked up in the delay table for the same date (non matching SKU'S) and they should be entered in the Status table with New delay as 1..Please find the DDL for the tables below

one of the other things to take care of is that if a SKU is not available in the mfg table on a particular mfg date and the SKU is only in the delay table on that specific mfgdate and is also available on the immediate previous delay date then that SKU will not be accounted for on that date
**delay table**

```
Create table delay
(mmodel varchar(40),
srno varchar(40),
snapdate date)

insert into delay values
('MX201','C12341','3/21/2021'),
('NM213','L1234','3/21/2021'),
('JK1231','K1561','3/21/2021'),
('KL1234','MJ1234','3/21/2021'),
('MX201','C12341','3/22/2021'),
('NM213','L1234','3/22/2021'),
('OP1231','JK123','3/22/2021'),
('MB321','LK123','3/22/2021'),
('MX201','C12341','3/23/2021'),
('BX378','H1231','3/23/2021'),
('LZ231','MD321','3/23/2021'),
('LO3412','LP1231','3/23/2021'),
('MX201','C12341','3/24/2021'),
('BX378','H1231','3/24/2021'),
('FE221','J6571','3/24/2021')

**Mfg table** 

Create table mfg
(mfgdate date),
mmodel varchar(40),
srno varchar(40),
)
insert into mfg values
('3/21/2021','JK123','K21310'),
('3/21/2021','KL378','L8941'),
('3/22/2021','JK1231','K1561'),
('3/22/2021','KL1234','MJ1234'),
('3/22/2021','KL918','S21367'),
('3/23/2021','NM213','L1234'),
('3/23/2021','OP1231','JK123'),
('3/23/2021','MB321','LK123'),
('3/23/2021','XC2312','M89321'),
('3/24/2021','LZ231','MD321'),
('3/24/2021','LO3412','LP1231'),
('3/24/2021','KL5612','D3489')

**Output table**
create table output 
(Dated date,
mmodel varchar(40),
srno varchar(40),
skucomplete int,
goodstock int,
offdelay int,
newdelay int
)

inert into output values
('3/22/2021','JK1231','K1561','1','0','1','0'),
('3/22/2021','KL1234','MJ1234','1','0','1','0'),
('3/22/2021','KL918','S21367','1','1','0','0'),
('3/22/2021','OP1231','JK123','0','0','0','1'),
('3/22/2021','MB321','LK123','0','0','0','1'),
('3/23/2021','NM213','L1234','1','0','1','0'),
('3/23/2021','OP1231','JK123','1','0','1','0'),
('3/23/2021','MB321','LK123','1','0','1','0'),
('3/23/2021','XC2312','M89321','1','1','0','0'),
('3/23/2021','BX378','H1231','0','0','0','1'),
('3/23/2021','LZ231','MD321','0','0','0','1'),
('3/23/2021','LO3412','LP1231','0','0','0','1'),
('3/24/2021','LO3412','LP1231','1','0','1','0'),
('3/24/2021','KL5612','D3489','1','1','0','0'),
('3/24/2021','FE221','J6571','0','0','0','1')
('3/24/2021','LZ231','MD321','1','0','1','0')
```

To summarize

1. The SKU from the mfg table and date should be taken and if the same SKU is present in the immediate previous date in the delay table then its status would be complete -1 and offdelay -1
2. The SKU from the mfg table and date should be taken and if the same SKU is not present in the immediate previous date in the delay table then its status would be complete -1 and goodstock-1
3. The SKU that is not present in mfg table on a specific date but is present in the delay table on that specific date (but the same SKU is not present in the immediate previous date in the delay table then its status would be just new delay -1

4)The SKU that is not present in mfg table on a specific date but is present in the delay table on that specific date (but the same SKU is present in the immediate previous date in the delay table then that SKU won't be in the output at all for that date...

**Query Tried**

```
SELECT M.mfgdate AS Dated,M.mmodel AS mmodel,M.srno AS srno
       ,1 AS skucomplete
       ,CASE WHEN D.mmodel IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS goodstock
       ,CASE WHEN D.mmodel IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS offdelay
       ,0 AS newdelay
 FROM mfg M LEFT JOIN delay D ON M.mfgdate=DATE_ADD(D.snapdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND M.mmodel=D.mmodel
 WHERE M.mfgdate>'3/21/2021'
 UNION ALL
 (
 SELECT snapdate,mmodel,srno,0 AS skucomplete,0 AS goodstock,0 AS offdelay,1 AS newdelay 
 FROM delay
 WHERE snapdate>'3/21/2021'
 AND NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT D1.snapdate,D1.mmodel,D1.srno,0 AS skucomplete,0 AS goodstock,0 AS offdelay,1 AS newdelay
 FROM delay D1 JOIN delay D2 ON D1.snapdate=DATE_ADD(D2.snapdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND D1.mmodel=D2.mmodel)
 )
 ORDER BY Dated
```

From the result of the above query I am getting values for only the skucompleted and goodstock as 1 ..I am not getting any values for offdelay and newdelay..

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Hi All, Any help on this question will be appreciated!

Comment: without considering the boolean-valued fields, can you explain how you get the `date` and SKUs (`mmodel`, `Srno`) in the `status` table?

Comment: @lemon: Appreciate your response!...First the mfgdate from the mfg table is taken to get the SKU’S that are manufactured on a particular day and then (SKU denoted by the combination of mmodel and srno) and then the SKUComplete is marked as 1 , To determine if the SKU is Goodstock or offdelay the delay table should be checked for the immediate previous day in comparison to the date in the mfg table and if the same SKU is present in the immediate previous date in the delay table then the SKU should be marked offdelay as 1 else the SKU should be marked Goodstock as 1

Comment: Now after going through all the SKU’S in the mfg table on a particular day the left out SKU’S in the delay table on the same date should be compared to the immediate  previous date in the delay table and if the SKU is not present in the immediate previous date then newdelay would be 1 otherwise offdelay would be 1 for the same SKU

Comment: I want to put attention on three SKUs which are in common to both tables "delay" and "mfg": the first one `LZ231 MD321` is retrieved only from the table "delay", the second one `NM213 L1234` is retrieved only from the table "mfg", the third one `LO3412 LP1231` is retrieved from both tables. Is there any hidden rule to take into account when retrieving the SKUs?

Comment: `'3/21/2021'` is not a valid value for a `DATE`.  Suggest you fix that before proceeding with this question.

Comment: @RickJames: Sure I will fix it now!

Comment: RickJames `STR_TO_DATE` can be a workaround for that issue

Comment: 5.6 does not have `LEAD()` and `LAG()` (windowing functions); can you update to 8.0 so you can get them?  If not the solution will be messier.

Comment: @lemon :LZ231 MD321 is retrieved from the table on 03/23 for delay as it is not present in the mfg table on that day..Also it has New delay as 1 for 03/23 as 03/22 in delay table doesnt have the SKU LZ231 MD321..

Comment: @RickJames: It is not possible to update my mysql version to 8.0 as I am using it as a part of another process..Sorry about the same

Comment: @lemon: NM123 L1234 is a part of mfg table on 03/23 and it is not there in the delay table on 03/23..Its there only on 03/22..Its same day to same day comparison

Comment: @lemon : LO3412 LP1231 is a part of the mfg table on 03/24 and not part of the delay table on 03/24 ...Its present in the delay table only on 03/23

Comment: @RickJames,@lemon: To give a general perspective ..The mfg table has the SKU'S (combination of mmodel and srno) that get manufactured on a particular day say 03/14..If the same SKU was present in the delay table on 03/13 then it means it means it has come off delay (out of delay) on 03/14 and got manufacturing completed..if the SKU that got manufacturing completed on 03/14 was not present in delay table on 03/13 then it implies that it is good stock since it was not in delayed status on the previous day...

Comment: Now on the same day of manufacturing completed there are other SKU'S that get  still remain in the delayed on the same day in the delayed file due to quality issues ..Now these SKU'S can be present only in the same date as the current manufacturing date in comparison in the delay file and not on the immediate previous date in the delay table..If this is the case then it is new delay ...if the SKU is not present in the mfg table and is present in delay table on the same date and also on the immediate previous date in the delay table then it is off delay too...

Comment: All the examples I raised attention upon are present in both tables with one day interval difference, though one of them is taken from the delay table, another one from the mfg table and the last one from both of them: it's not clear to me the rationale behind how to discriminate among these three.

Comment: Hi @lemon: The primary table where I go and pickup the SKU'S are from the mfg table (or the manufacturing table)...Here the SKU'S are manufacturing completed so they move to storage..Now the delay table has the SKU'S that are marked as delayed during the manufacturing process , so before a SKU can be manufacturing completed on a particular date the previous date it might be on delay status (if this happens then it is called as off delay - meaning it came off the delay status today and it got manufacturing completed)..

Comment: Now there are SKU'S which dont get manufacturing completed on a particualar date in the mfg table...(meaning they are not present in the mfg table on a particular mfgdate)..If this happens they can be in delay table as New delay (meaning they were not in the delay status in the immediate previous day)(All the delay status SKU'S are present in the delay table)..Now if a SKU was present on the previous date and on the current date too in the delay table then it means that the SKU continues to be in the delay status and they are not expected to be in the final output table..

Comment: @lemon : So the mode of getting to the output table is as follows : Picking up the SKU'S from the mfg table and if they were present in the previous date in the delay table then its called offdelay (1 on offdelay column) otherwise it is goodstock.. For the remaining SKU'S (non matching SKU'S in the delay on the same date if the SKU is present only on a particular date or not on a previous date then it is called new delay (if it was present on the previous date and also the current date in the delay table then they are ignored..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Arun. According to it, should the output table contain `LZ231 MD321` associated to `2021-03-24` instead of its current date value (`2021-03-23`)?

Comment: Hi @lemon : It will be there on both the dates...on 03-23 as new delay (this is because although it was not in the mfg table on 03-23 it was there on delay table on 03-23 and not in dealy table on 03-22 so it would be new delay 1 and on 03-24 as SKU Completed as it is in the mfg table on 03-24

Answer (score 0):

It seems like

```
SELECT mmodel, Srno, MAX(Snapdate) AS latest_delay
    FROM delays
    GROUP BY mmodel, Srno;
```

would be handy in providing the `latest_delay` for any mmodel+srno.  Maybe include that somehow in the ultimate query?

Comment: Hi @Rick James, I am not sure if that would be handy as the dates in comparison are the current date and the immediate previous date...